# Showing text info in window split separators

Tags: neovim, vim-windows, split

(I'm using nvim 0.7 and have recently moved from a init.vim to lua, which is baffling me slightly.)

In my old set-up a split would look like this:

[image: screenshot]

→ note that the bar that splits the two windows contains info on the window above it.

In my new set-up, the bar that splits the windows is just blank. I've searched through my old (long) config for anything related to splits and can't find anything I did to achieve that before!

Is this a built-in setting somewhere? (I'm also confused re talk of "winbar" which seems to be a new feature in neovim 0.8, and possibly vim, but I've had this behaviour for years).

Comment: you want to check what kind of a fancy statusline plugin you used previously. Check out vim-airline or lualine specifically for Neovim. Also check your 'laststatus' setting

Answer (score 1):

It’s the `laststatus` config. `set laststatus=2` fixes.

> The value of this option influences when the last window will have a
> status line:
>
> 0: never
> 1: only if there are at least two windows
> 2: always
> 3: always and ONLY the last window

Thanks for [Christian's comment](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/38199/showing-text-info-in-window-split-separators?noredirect=1#comment69689_38199)